# Virtualenv: deactivate not working

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I had a venv called "MyAppEnv" that I was using and I tried to write a script I could run that would call `source bin/activate` (save me some keystrokes). I accidentally ran it while already in MyAppEnv. Since doing this, when I try to deactivate MyAppEnv, I get `bash: type: deactivate: not found`. This happens even in the brand-new environment I created, totally separate from MyAppEnv. How do I get it back? I cannot exit out of my environment except by killing my screen session.

Comment: All you have to do is unset or reset all the variables that activate did. You will need to reset `PATH` to the previous value. You will need to unset `PYTHON` and `PYTHON_PATH`. There may be more in your venv. Familiarize yourself by reading the activate script in `MyAppEnv`.

Comment: As you found out, activating a virtualenv does not work like that in a shell script. Install mkvirtualenv to be lazy. The deactivate command is just an alias that unsets a few variables. Don't run your shell script.

Comment: @alvits That doesn't sound too bad. Could you be more specific as to how I would reset these variables/what I would set them to? I don't have much shell know-how and don't want to screw things up further. $PYTHON and $PYTHON_PATH are currently empty strings - what should they be? I'm assuming $PYTHON_PATH is the folder where Python lives, but what about just the var $PYTHON?

Comment: If they're empty strings, leave them alone. Check the contents of `PATH`. Venv activate prepends the `MyAppEnv/bin` in there. Example: `echo $PATH` might show something like `/home/username/virtualenv/MyAppenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`. All you need to do is remove the first entry. `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @alvits Okay, I have changed the path, but I am still in my venv (or at least my prompt is still prepended by its name) and deactivate still does not work.

Comment: @alvits Before I changed the path, it looked like this: `/home/<my name>/my_project/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/e(my_(my_(my(m(my_project)`. Help!

Comment: The prompt is another issue. It's one of the variables that need to be reset. The variable is `PS1`. I would not know what your prompt was. Let's assume your prompt was `hostname:path username$`, you can set it back to that value with `export PS1=\h:\W \u\$`.

Comment: You can reset your `PATH` with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbi‌​n`.

Comment: After resetting these variables, you don't need to deactivate. This is exactly what deactivate does.

Comment: @alvits Killed all my screen sessions, reactivated my venv, and now everything is fine - deactivate works like it did before and my path is back to normal. I have no idea what happened.